# How can I pass data in run method (thread) (python, Pyqt)

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

I want to make the thread, in the window, using PyQt(Python). For example

```
class window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hello')
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(u'WoRLd', self)
        self.Layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.Layout)
        self.introduced = 123


        self.request = Requests()
        self.request.start()

        self.connect(self.request, QtCore.SIGNAL("mysignal(QString)"),
            self.on_change, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def on_change(self, s):
        self.label.setText(s)

class Requests():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("mysignal(QString)"), "143242" )


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = window()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But, in method "run", I need some dates from "class window" (variable: introduced). 
How can I pass this variable to "def run"?

Comment: Just calling `QThread.__init__` in your initializer doesn't make you a `QThread`. You need to inherit from `QThread` as well: `class Requests(QtCore.QThread)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to make arguments for it and pass it into the class instance. then assign it to self.date, this makes it accesible across the class instance:

```
class window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hello')
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(u'WoRLd', self)
        self.Layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.Layout)
        self.introduced = 123
        date = # get some date whatever you need to pass here

        self.request = Requests(date)
        self.request.start()

        self.connect(self.request, QtCore.SIGNAL("mysignal(QString)"),
            self.on_change, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def on_change(self, s):
        self.label.setText(s)

class Requests():
    def __init__(self, date, parent=None):
        self.date = date
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        # do something with self.date here
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("mysignal(QString)"), "143242" )


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = window()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```